# How can I list the AWS IAM groups in which I am a member?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

The title says it all, really. Given an AWS access key and secret, it it possible to get a list of IAM groups to which the user belongs? Is any self-introspection possible with the AWS APIs?

Edit: The question is assuming that no other privileges are granted other than being part of a group itself. For example, this particular IAM user only has permissions to read from an ECR repo and does not have privileges to call `list-groups-for-user`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you do not have permission to call `iam:ListGroupsForUser`, or `iam:ListGroups` + `iam:GetGroup`, then you're out of luck*.  The only API operation that an AWS principal can call without an explicit permission is `sts:GetCallerIdentity` (apart from a few API actions that do not require AWS credentials at all, such as `sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` and parts of Cognito), which returns the identity of the principal whose credentials were used to call it.  There are no permissionless API actions to list the permissions of a principal, list its group memberships, or anything like that.

*I'm not sure what errors `iam:AddUserToGroup` and `iam:RemoveUserFromGroup` return if the user already is or is not a member of the target group.  It's possible that they might reveal group membership -- but if you don't have permission for `iam:ListGroupsForUser`, you're highly unlikely to have permissions for these.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

*If specific permissions have been granted for the user to run the command.*

From the docs `list-groups-for-user`:

> Lists the IAM groups that the specified IAM user belongs to. `list-groups-for-user` is a paginated operation. Multiple API calls may be issued in order to retrieve the entire data set of results.

You can do something like this:

```bash
aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name Bob
```

Which sould output something like this:

```json
"Groups": [
    {
        "Path": "/",
        "CreateDate": "2013-05-06T01:18:08Z",
        "GroupId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:group/Admin",
        "GroupName": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "Path": "/",
        "CreateDate": "2013-05-06T01:37:28Z",
        "GroupId": "AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:group/s3-Users",
        "GroupName": "s3-Users"
    }
]
```

Full documentation on `list-groups-for-user` is [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/iam/list-groups-for-user.html).

Comment: Note for OP: it is also possible that the given credentials are simply not allowed to perform that action.

Comment: @baduker Thanks for the answer. This does require a specific permission to be granted, though, as luk2302 mentioned. Just belonging to a group does not allow me to use this API. I was hoping there would be an alternative, but it seems unlikely. I'll update my question accordingly for future readers.